# Is there an event triggered for opening a devtools?

Tags: javascript, browser, devtools

As is obvious by the question title, I need a callback for an event related to opening a devtools, like

```
    /* I expect for something like that with var "devtools" as window's object or the instanceof an unknowed class  */

    devtools.onDevtoolsOpened = () =>
    {
        // do my stuff
    }
```

If it's possible, I ask for help. But if not, is there a related action or another way to fulfill my wish?

Comment: What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), why do you feel a need to detect devtools opening? What is `// do my stuff`?

Comment: I want to delete a specific script when someone tries a code check on a specific page. It's to prevent some kind of cheating

Comment: That's not gonna work. People can always see the code of your page, they don't even need devtools for that. But the devtools record executed code on the sources tab, removing the script afterwards won't help anyway. Sure you can try to make it harder, but ultimately all cheating prevention needs to happen on the server side.

Comment: I didn't even know that we could access scripts without devtools ! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on each individual browser. However, I found a module that does the trick for most of the browsers:
[devtools-detect](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect)
From their documentation:

```
<script src="node_modules/devtools-detect/index.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    // Check if it's open
    console.log('Is DevTools open:', window.devtools.isOpen);

    // Check it's orientation, `undefined` if not open
    console.log('DevTools orientation:', window.devtools.orientation);

    // Get notified when it's opened/closed or orientation changes
    window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', event => {
        console.log('Is DevTools open:', event.detail.isOpen);
        console.log('DevTools orientation:', event.detail.orientation);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "*Doesn't work if DevTools is undocked and will show false positive if you toggle any kind of sidebar.*" - wow.

Comment: Yeah, that' is bad. However the repo is kinda popular and, depending on the use case it could still work, thus my answer.

Comment: I first thought of capturing devtools call keys (F12, ctrl + maj + i, ctrl+maj+c, ... )but I immediately saw that it would not work if that person goes through the menu of the browser.